# Error occurred while installing xamarin with Visual studio 2013 in Windows 8.1

Tags: xamarin, installation, window

I tried to install xamarin as mentioned in xamarin.com . it continue the process and gives following errors.

[image: error one]

[image: error two]

I tried to install those manually, but it also failed.

Note : I'm using visual studio 2013 (ultimate) in windows 8.1.
do I have to update visual studio to 2015 or any other solution with this.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to install manually?

Comment: I try to install manually, first try android sdk ,now it show following error
`It is very important to install the 32-bit version of Java JDK even if you're using 64-bit Windows. It is also important that Java JDK v1.6 is installed (although it is fine to have Java JDK 1.7 or newer installed at the same time)` 

and also , same error for xamarin

Comment: So you have to install Java SDK first then from oracle's website http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html Make sure you install correct version for your machine architecture.